# Braided Para cord Devices with Tools Contained Therein (Bison Designs, Llc) Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130031935

**HELP SAVE SURVIVAL BRACELET MAKERS** - This application from Bison Designs, Llc seeks to patent Braided Para cord Devices with Tools Contained Therein! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow this US patent application before it becomes a patent.

QUESTION - Have you seen anything that was published before 5 aug 2011 that discusses:

A paracord survival bracelet with tools contained therein

If you've ever seen anything like this before, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question -- one piece of prior art per answer. We welcome multiple answers from a single individual.

TITLE: Braided Para cord Devices with Tools Contained Therein

Summary: A paracord bracelet is disclosed which includes a blade with a loop as a handle that can be encased in the braiding to form the loop part of a closure mechanism. In a further embodiment the bracelet includes a pieces of flint formed into a solid piece to form the tab and/or toggle part of a closure mechanism. This combination of devices means that the user has a means of making a fire with them whenever they are wearing the bracelet, in addition to the paracord. In an additional embodiment a key fob is made of paracord enclosing a blade, a flint and tender. Another embodiment the bracelet includes fishing gear, including a steel cable leader set with a clasp hook, swivel, lure and other items. In the depicted embodiment the bracelet is design with the swivel and the clasp hook forming the bracelet closure mechanism.

Publication Number: US20130031935 (https://www.google.com/patents/US20130031935?dq=survival+bracelet+patent&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=IldfUpGIE4mYlQXz_4GYBw&ved=0CFMQ6AEwAw)
Assignee: Bison Designs, Llc
Prior Art Date: Seeking prior Art predating 5 Aug 2011

Claim 1 requires each and every structural aspect below:

- A bracelet comprising:
- a body formed from braided paracord having a first and second end;
- a closure mechanism for the bracelet formed in two parts, each of said part being attached to the first and second end respectively;
- at least one of the closure mechanisms being an item that is a tool usable for a task other than closing the bracelet.

In English this means:

A paracord bracelet with two ends and a closure mechanism that can be used as a tool for something else than closing the bracelet.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 5 Aug 2011.

Please help saving the survival paracord bracelet makers by providing prior art! This "invention" does not deserve a patent.

Answer (score 1):

If the whistle buckle is sufficient there is ample evidence of the use of whistle buckles in paracord bracelets prior to the date in question.

A picture is here
http://www.zombiehunters.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=38163&start=96

Instructables has a belt but not a bracelet tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This survival bracelet was posted in May 2011 on this (link below) and other online forums. It was the first to include the scraping device and ferrocerium toggle. http://www.wilderness-survival.net/forums/showthread.php?16290-Best-paracord-survival-bracelet-firesteel-tinder-scraper-and-sling&s=5e1b1a7057a93dcc3676f8a9bb55f581&p=298207&viewfull=1#post298207